# Laravel 6 authentication protecting routes

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've got a problem and since L6 is new, I haven't found a solution.

How can I protect my admin panel routes? 
For now I've got authentication set:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return view('admin.home');
    })->middleware('auth');
```

but when link inside view is clicked, suddenly it's unauthenticated again.
Also, how can I protect other routes inside admin?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    //Your authenticated route define at here
});
```

Comment: Great! it solves half of my problem. I can now group links with auth. but it still gives "unauthenticated" when moving in another protected link

Comment: No sure what you mean. So you just simple put all route on the same auth group. Did you put them on group yet ?

Comment: Did you tamper with the session configuration?

Comment: Yes, my routes are in group. @Namoshek mentioned session. and I'll try that